# Problems with list of map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Questao.dart';
import 'Resposta.dart';

main() => runApp(PerguntaApp());

class _PerguntaAppState extends State<PerguntaApp> {
  var _perguntaSelecionada = 0;

  _responder() {
    setState(() {
      _perguntaSelecionada++;
    });
    print(_perguntaSelecionada);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Map<String, Object>> perguntas = [
      {
        "texto": "Qual e a sua cor favorita?",
        "resposta": ["Azul", "Preto", "Vermelho", "Verde"],
      },
      {
        "texto": "Qual e o seu animal favorito?",
        "resposta": ["Baleia", "Leao", "Cobra", "Elefante"],
      },
      {
        "texto": "Qual e o seu instructor favorito?",
        "resposta": ["Maria", "Joao", "Leo", "Atila"],
      }
    ];

    var respostas = [];
    for(String textResp in perguntas[_perguntaSelecionada]["resposta"]) {
      respostas.add(Resposta(textResp,_responder));
    }

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Perguntas"),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Questao(perguntas[_perguntaSelecionada]["texto"]),
                ...respostas,
              ],
            )));
  }
}

class PerguntaApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _PerguntaAppState createState() {
    return _PerguntaAppState();
  }
}
```

Guys, i just can't unsderstand what am doing wrong, there is a huge red line in `perguntas[_perguntaSelecionada]["texto"]` and i just can't understand why, there is no comma between them, in the variable `perguntas` everything is well set(as far as i can tell) but it's still saying

'2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.'

What in the hell am i doing wrong?

Here is also the constructor of the widget Questao:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Questao extends StatelessWidget {
  final String texto;
  Questao(this.texto, List<String> list);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Text(
        texto,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Questao(arg1, arg2)` constructor, the errors says the constructor takes two arguments but you are giving it only one.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your feedback, but i already know that the problem is in Questao, what i'm asking is, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: you're adding only one argument which is `perguntas[_perguntaSelecionada]["texto"]`, show me the constructor's implementation of `Questao` and maybe I can tell you how to fix it

Comment: you have to add two arguments, not one

Answer (score 0):

fix your `Questao` class

```
class Questao extends StatelessWidget {
  final String texto;
  Questao({this.texto});
```

Now call it like this

```
Questao(texto: perguntas[_perguntaSelecionada]["texto"].toString()),
```

If you want to pass two arguments then fix your Questao class like this

```
class Questao extends StatelessWidget {
      final String texto;
      final List<String> list;
      Questao({this.texto, this.list});
```